# how to pass args to bash functions

Tags: bash, shell

I have written simple bash code to check the working of bash function , I found few code on internet showing similar examples like this, but as I did by own I am unable to retrieve the args value inside my function.

```
#!/bin/bash

function function_name() {
echo "inside function"
echo  "$arg1"
}

var="muddassir"
function_name $var
```

This is the output I am getting while executing this script

```
$ ./test.sh
inside function
```

Comment: `echo  "$1"` instead of `echo  "$arg1"`, the positional arguments in `bash` start from `$1` and total count will be `$#`

Comment: Very fast solution :)